# How to include resources in a BALA file

Tags: ballerina

When I'm packing a ballerina project in a BALA file with `bal pack`, I need to pack some resources that are in the ballerina project into the BALA.

I tried packing the resources inside the ballerina project but it didn't get packed in the BALA.

```
|- main.bal
|- Ballerina.toml
|- resources
   |- help.txt
```

I need to pack help.txt in the BALA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [include field](https://ballerina.io/learn/package-references/#the-include-field) of the [package] table in the Ballerina.toml to pack any resources in the BALA. Here you can use a file path relative to the root of the package or a gitignore type wildcard to pack the files.

```
[package]
include = [“resources/help.txt”]
```

or,

```
[package]
include = [“resources/*.txt”, “*.png”]
```